# .NET Core: MySqlConnector refusing to connect to AWS RDS instance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, amazon-rds, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect my MySql database thats on an AWS RDS instance to my .NET core API I am creating using MySqlConnector nuget package.  I can connect to my database instance in MySqlWorkbench and through the terminal, however my project is is getting sent to the wrong endpoint.

In my project I have the following to open the database:

```
public class Database : IDisposable
    {
        public MySqlConnection Connection;

        public Database(string connectionString)
        {
            Connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
            this.Connection.Open();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

When debugging, I can view the connection string in the MySqlConnection object, and the connection string is (with some fields blocked out):

```
"Server=database.[...].rds.amazonaws.com;user=******;password=*********;"
```

The connection string is correct in the Connection object, however, when ran it throws an exception that connection was refused to username@[...].res.rr.com when it hits the Connection.Open().  This is NOT the url that was in the connection string.  I cannot connect to this url through MySQLWorkbench or terminal either.  How I am being send this this other URL when it is nowhere in my solution?  I have no clue where this other url is coming from.

Comment: Well, I am making an app for a personal project, and its either make an API or web service to connect a database to it for multiple devices to use.  The only alternative would be to directly access the database from the Xamarin project which seems like a pretty messy coding practice.

Comment: The API would have to be public for a mobile app.  The DB instance itself is not nor will be public itself.  If the API was not public then that defeats the point of a mobile app as the IP address changes.  Regardless, the issue I was having is related to my code trying to connect via an endpoint I dont recognize that isnt in the connection string.  I can connect to my DB instance fine via MySqlWorkbench or terminal, so the issue isn't with VPC settings unless I am unaware of something.  I am running the project and connecting in terminal off of the same IP.

Comment: I've totally missed that, sorry, thought you could _not_ connect at all.

Comment: @thesongib any update about the reason ?

Comment: I believe that this is due to aws rds using a dns, and mysqlconnector.net having issues with connecting to the endpoint, since it returns several different ips. I'm working on this, and in some workstations it connects with no errors. Try checking the bugs on its github page, apparently for some works to specify the tls version on the connection string.
https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/1074